# Shortcut of mouse's right-click (Shift f10) does not work in some applications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, editors

I know that the shortcut of mouse's right-click is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. I use it frequently in libreoffice, and I also try it in applications such as Firefox.

However, in some case as in Texmaker, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, nothing happens. I have also checked the list of shortcuts of Texmaker to be sure there is no conflict.

What is the reason of this issue and what is the solution to resolve it?

Comment: Which distro and desktop environment? At least in KDE, this doesn't seem to be a setting controlled globally, so it must be defined (by convention) in each application. The action is "show context menu" or similar.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Based on your idea I have made a test of currently available applications in my machine: GTK apps: nautilus, evince, etc., KDE apps: kile, okular, etc., Qt apps: vlc, qtcreator, etc. I found that only in GTK apps the Shift + F10 shortcut works. Therefore, it seems to be the answer of the question. Again, thank you very much for your help. Btw, I use Ubuntu 16.10 and dwm as desktop environment.